# heatmap using highcharts javascript from a csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts, heatmap

Hi I'm trying to create a heatmap using Highcharts library. I am taking data from a CSV file. 
My CSV file has three parameters which is:

```
Events,Apps,Status
Business Requirement Description,App1,60
Communication to Stake Holders,App1,50
Development Started,App1,30
Reviewed ,App1,10
Ready for E2E Testing,App1,5
Business Requirement Description,App2,80
Communication to Stake Holders,App2,40
Development Started,App2,20
Reviewed ,App2,10
Ready for E2E Testing,App2,0
Business Requirement Description,App3,100
Communication to Stake Holders,App3,60
Development Started,App3,0
Reviewed ,App3,30
Ready for E2E Testing,App3,0
```

Importing the required files:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
```

This is my Javascript code to initialize:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {var options = {
chart: {
    renderTo:'container',
    type : 'heatmap',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 80,
    plotBorderWidth: 1
},
title: {
    text: 'DIT HeatMap Sample'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: []
},
yAxis: {
categories: [],
    title: {
        text: 'Apps'
    }
},
series: [{}]
};
```

Defining the colorAxis, tooltip and  Legend:

```
  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    ***minColor: '#FFFFFF'***,
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]},
 legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 280},
     tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> is <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        }
```

Below is my code to read the CSV file which is placed in same location as my html file.

```
 //Fetching the CSV data

    $.get('DITData.csv', function(data){
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line){
        var items = line.split(','); 
        })
    // Defining X-Axis: 

        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item){
        if(itemNo == 0){
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line){
        if (lineNo > 0)
        options.xAxis.categories.push(item)});
        }
    // Defining X-Axis: 

        else if (itemNo == 1){
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line){
        if (lineNo > 0)
        options.yAxis.categories.push(item)});
        }
        else {
                var series = {
                data: []
                };
// Defining the series:

    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line){
        if (lineNo > 0)
        series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
        });
        options.series.push(series);    

    }
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});

</script> 
</head>
```

And Finally calling the container in the body.

```
<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
```

But I am not getting any output, I have followed the tutorials and syntax and my own logic, I'm not sure what is wrong. Console says unexpected error at Line that I showed in bold and italics.
Any expert in Highcharts or JavaScript here, Please help me out!!

Thanks a ton in advance !!